# Power BI desktop loading sequence

Tags: powerbi, sequence, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-api

Is there a way to set up a loading sequence for the elements in a desktop dashboard so that the slicer will always load first even though other elements might still be loading?
(i.e I change 1 slicer filter and the dashboard starts loading. Now I want to change a filter from another slicer, but I have to wait for the changes made from the first slicer to be loaded before seeing the different options to select from in the second slicer)
So I want the slicer to always load first, even though other elements might still be loading (as the slicer only takes 2 seconds to load whereas I need to wait 30 seconds for some matrices)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt there's an official way, but I'd also consider it likely that PBI uses some simple sequence based on the order in which the controls were added combined with a limit on parallelism (disclaimer: not tested). You could try making a new page that's the old page by gradually copying over controls in the desired loading order to see if I'm in any way on the ball there.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Excel you can't select all filter before the update of the visual.
Each modification of slicer would launch a request for your visuals.

The work around is to create another page with slicer synchronize with the same slicer on your page with visuals and switch on this page when you have properly parametrize your request.